# Obtener informacion de un archivo y guardarlo en un txt mediante Python

Tags: python, imagen, script, txt

Hola que tal? Estoy aprendiendo un poco de Python y necesito una ayuda con un problema.
Estoy tratando de obtener la información de un archivo( en este caso imágenes) y guardar esa info en un .txt.
Me interesa el nombre de la imagen, la dimensión y el tipo de extension.
Por ejemplo : imagen "x" , 450 x 390 extension= .tif, jpg, etc

Por ahora voy con esto

```
import os


path = "D:/imagenes/input"

dirs = os.listdir( path )


for file in dirs:
   print (file)
```

Esto solo me dice da una lista de archivos tengo en la carpeta, pero no su info ni como guardarla.
Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias

Comment: te recomiendo investigar `PIL`

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la extensión, puedes usar `os.path.splitext`

```
import os


path = "D:/imagenes/input"
dirs = os.listdir(path)


for file in dirs:
    print(file)
    print(os.path.splitext(file)[1])
```

`os.path.splitext(foo)` crea un un arreglo de dos elementos: el primer elemento contiene el nombre de `foo` sin la extensión, el segundo elemento contiene únicamente la extensión.

Para obtener la altura y anchura de la imagen, puedes usar la librería [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/), específicamente `PIL.Image`:

```
from PIL import Image


with Image.open(filepath) as imagen:
    ancho, alto= imagen.size
    print(f"{ancho}x{alto}")
```

El atributo `size` devuelve una tupla de dos elementos, la altura y la anchura. [La documentación detalla más funciones](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html)

Existen varias maneras de guardar estos datos, como guardarlos en tuplas/arreglos o en archivos `.txt`. Dependiendo de tus fines, alguno será mejor que otro.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Intente hacer lo que me has dicho pero como soy bastante nuevo y estoy aprendiendo me genero unas dudas. Me dice que filepath no esta definido.  Revise la libreria y me sirve para lo que necesito, pero no entiendo lo de filepath

Comment: @Rodrigo `filepath` es la variable con el nombre del fichero, lo que en en código anterior está como `file`. A propósito: no se debería usar `file` como nombre de variable ya es el nombre de una función estándar de python.

Answer (score 0):

Lo recomendable a estas alturas es usar el módulo [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html) para manejo de las rutas de ficheros. Casi todas las librerías lo usan, incluida *Pillow*.

Para obtener el nombre de los ficheros, su extensión y sus dimensiones:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image

PATH = Path("/ruta/a/los/ficheros")

for fname in PATH.iterdir():
    if fname.is_file():
        name = fname.name
        ext = fname.suffix
        realpath = str(fname.resolve())

        try:
            with PIL.Image.open(fname) as im:
                width, height = im.size
        except:
            width, height = (0, 0)

        print(f"{name} - {ext} ({width}x{height})")
        print(f"Path: {realpath}")
```

Te recomiendo que eches una lectura al módulo [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
    import os
from PIL import Image

path = "D:imagenes/input"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

for filename in dirs:

    print(filename)
    print(os.path.splitext(filename)[1])

    imagen = Image.open(filename)    
    ancho, alto= imagen.size
    print(f"{ancho}x{alto}")
```

Bueno al final comparto lo que pude hacer, cambiando algunos detalles me ha quedado así, ahora solo me falta lograr que esa información de la imagen la pueda guardar en un XML. Agradezco a todos por ayudarme, voy a seguir buscando como terminar este script